# Apache Druid throws "OSError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"

Tags: python-3.x, druid, pydruid

I encounter with an Error when I try to reach Apache Druid datasource. Here is the code sample I used to load Druid datasource into pandas dataframe:

```
from pydruid.client import *
from pydruid.utils.aggregators import doublesum
from pydruid.utils.filters import Dimension

query = PyDruid("http://10.XXX.XX.XXX:8082/", 'druid/v2/sql')

ts = query.timeseries(
    datasource='mallCustomers',
    granularity='all',
    intervals='2015-01-01/pt1h',
    aggregations={"count": doublesum("Age")},
    filter=Dimension('Age') == 18
)
df = query.export_pandas()
```

1. 10.XXX.XX.XXX is my Query node
2. pydurid==0.6.5

I also tried port 8083, but it also throws urllib.error.URLError

How can I reach druid table via Python ? I can't find robust guideline or tutorial for this, and the ones I found throw similar errors.

Can you help me on this one ?

Here is the full error:

```
OSError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request 
 Druid Error: b'{"error":"Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.druid.sql.http.SqlQuery`, problem: query\\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 255]"}' 
 Query is: {
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "fieldName": "Age",
            "name": "count",
            "type": "doubleSum"
        }
    ],
    "dataSource": "mallCustomers",
    "filter": {
        "dimension": "Age",
        "type": "selector",
        "value": 18
    },
    "granularity": "all",
    "intervals": "2015-01-01/pt1h",
    "queryType": "timeseries"
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```